# Had an odd observation/result from hexadecimal math in LESS. Why is this the case?

Tags: css, less

I just started working with LESS and so far it's been alright. However, I met a peculiar situation wherein a background was allocated the color (#03A9F4 - 100). My intuition coupled with my understanding of hexadecimal numbers, from the little IT taken during college (I am not of CS background), would obviously lead me to think that the resulting (CSS) color code would be #03A8F4. This wasn't the case in the document I was using, though. It had #004590 as the result.

So, what is it that I am not getting?

**Less Code**

```
@div-width: 100px;
@color: #03A9F4;

#left{
  width: @div-width;
  background-color: @color - 100;
}
```

**Resulting CSS Code**

```
#left {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #004590;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code snippet with the problem?

Comment: @SergeyDenisov There you have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not *exactly* sure of the math that is happening behind-the-scenes, but it's easily deduced.

**Short answer**:

LESS converts the numbers to decimal, per channel, to perform the subtraction, then re-converts back to hex.

**Long answer**:

If you change the `100` to `#100`:

```
background-color: #03A9F4 - #100
```

the output is

```
background-color: #00a9f4;
```

The `#100` is shorthand here for `#110000`, so only the red channel is affected.

Now, when subtracting a *number* instead of a *color*, LESS treats it a bit differently. Let's break it up by channel this time as well.

Original color: `#03A9F4`, Output: `#004590`

**Red** `03 -> 00`

**Blue** `A9 -> 45`

**Green** `F4 -> 90`

Since the red channel doesn't tell us much, we'll look at the other channels.

For blue, `A9` in decimal is `169`. Subtracting 100 gives us leaves 69. What is 69 (decimal) in hex? It's `45`.

For green, `F4` in decimal is `244`. Subtracting 100 leaves 144, which is `90` in hex.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This certainly makes sense.